# Adding a dollar sign next to a span?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, frontend

I'm working on a budget app that lets the user write in their budget and as many expenses as the user wishes.
The total budget, expenses, and balance (each of these is a span tag in HTML) are kept in a container div.

I want to add a dollar sign next to each of these spans. How do I add a dollar sign that sits right next to the amount? I need to make it a separate tag from the money tags.

I tried adding it in the form of a template string such as

```
amount.innerHTML = `$${tempAmount}`
expenditureValue.innerText = `$${sum};
```

However, doing this results in messing up with numbers adding together. Adding more than one expense results in "NaN" appearing on the page.

I also tried adding it into the HTML page, but the dollar sign is skewed from the number result. It ends up looking like:

```
$
    10000
```

Any advice on what I can do?

Comment: Use [stack snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to share the problem with us on the site.

Comment: Use psuedo-element ::before in css to add $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you have a class for the element, or the ability to add a class, you can always add a pseudo-element and set its content using CSS.

```js
const num = document.querySelector('.amount').textContent = 20;
```

```css
.amount::before {
  content: '$';
}
```

```html
<div class="amount"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to add the symbol code. I think it make your code easier.

```
amount.innerHTML = `&#36;${tempAmount}`
```